# On periods of symmetric algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric finite dimensional algebra over a field of characteristic two (or even over the field with two elements) such that every simple $A$-module has the same period equal to $n$.

> Question: Is the period of the algebra $A$ also equal to $n$?

This is not true in other characteristics, but I am not aware of an example in characteristic two, but there probably is one out there.